# Android Intent for media player plays mp3 but does not display information(Title, Artist, Album Art)

Tags: android

It is very easy to call an intent for the native Android Media Player to play an MP3 file. e.g.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
 Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/bigTune.mp3"); 
 intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/mp3"); 
    try { 
         startActivity(intent); 
        } 
           catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
```

The Problem is that when the player starts the file plays and the album art CD is blank and the player shows NO song Information.

If the same was to be done through a file manager like Astro file Manager, I would see the song Information (Title, Artist Album Art)

Is there any thing else that i need to know to add to the Intent or something else that I need to do to enable the Media Player to show the mp3's Info ???

Thanks is advance

Comment: I believe that different android media players show different things. The media player in 2.1 shows the info I need, but not 2.2

Comment: does the media player show the information when you open the mp3 file directly?

Comment: Have a look at this: www.github.com/avafab/URLMediaPlayer 
you can customize the code to display what you want.